# Prove or disprove the following claim in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider an LP in standard form, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},\ c\in \mathbb{R}^n,\ b\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Suppose the set of optimal solutions is bounded. Is it true that all optimal solutions have at most $m$  nonzeroes.

If true, give a proof.
If not, give a counter-example.

The problem I'm facing is firstly, I dont quite understand what does the problem mean by "bounded". Is it saying that there are only finite number of optimal solution ?

And how does this relate to the number of zeroes in the optimal solution, I cant find the intuition behind this claim.

Any help or insight on how to approach this problem is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The optimal solution is bounded means that the objective function does not run away to $+\infty$. The simplest case occurs when the feasible set is compact.

Comment: I dont quite understand, can you elaborate on this a bit more? Thank you

Comment: The feasible set of a LP problem may be bounded or not. When it is bounded, the maximum always exists. When it is not, the objective function may be unbounded and the problem has no solution. In short, the statement of the problem tells you not to worry whether the max is attained (it is).

Comment: As per solutions, look into the result that the optimum is attained at a vertex of the polytope constituting the feasible set.

Comment: "The set of optimal solutions is bounded" means that it is not an extreme ray of the polyhedron constituting the feasible set. Therefore there exist either a single optimal vertex or many optimal vertices. Every vertex, by definition, has at most $m$ nonzeros. The set of optimal solutions can be expressed as a convex combination of the optimal vertices......